# How can I use a leaflet layer control to toggle a d3 svg overlay?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, svg, d3.js

I have 3 d3 svgs I want to put on the same leaflet map. I would like to be able to control them with the same ease as leaflet layers.

Here is **[code that works](https://gist.github.com/amiri/8231660)**, but is janky.

The relevant part is lines 75 to the end, where I create a custom layer control tied specifically to my d3 svg group, instantiate it, and pop it in the overlays hash before addTo(map).

```
var lineLayer = L.Class.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    return;
  },
  onAdd: function (map) {
    railLineGroup.style("display", "block");
  },
  onRemove: function (map) {
    railLineGroup.style("display", "none");
  },
});
var railLineLayer = new lineLayer();
overlays["Rail Lines"] = railLineLayer;
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

There's got to be a better way to do this. For instance, because this is a hack, the layer control does not know that the layer has already been activated, so the checkbox is unchecked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I really would recommend you to have a look at [Vector OSM](https://github.com/rsudekum/vector-osm), specially at [tilejson.js](https://github.com/rsudekum/vector-osm/blob/gh-pages/js/tilejson.js). There you see a proper implementation which makes layer control work with SVG overlay.